# cell division to simulate cancer cells duplicating out of control

Tags: animation-nodes

I want to create a procedural animation of cells dividing and multiplying. I would like to use animation nodes and have 1 cell divide into 2 - then those divide, etc., etc. [This](https://www.instagram.com/p/B-cDUl4D8OR/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link) is an example of what I'm trying to do.

I am new to animation nodes, but think that it should be possible with the loop subprogram.

Has anyone created anything like this?

Comment: something like this...https://www.instagram.com/p/B-cDUl4D8OR/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

Comment: In your example it looks like the cells are emitting from a point and not splitting from each separate cells.If that is the case it's easy to do with AN and rigidbodies. Here is the one i made:[link](https://ibb.co/jwrMWCw).

Answer (score 0):

Meta-balls work great for cells, look under add/meta-balls/balls.
Meta-balls animated looks like mitosis 
[image]

Comment: thanks. Yes, I am using metaballs and they do look great. What I am looking for help with is how to procedurally make them divide. It's easy if I am animating one, but I want thousands of them dividing and duplicating.

Comment: Animation nodes maybe an answer. thing of Array on streoids https://animation-nodes.com/?fbclid=IwAR2RJbRbzIZzoGWvipR49v6ZuYMyh-Dlx7W3ECyA83CgTLfJGOdDmEKZ-m8#get-started